# How to create and call a dynamically created control from a seperate class?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I call and capture the events of a dynamically created control (e.g. TextBox) from a class (e.g. ControlHandler)? I have created some controls in my form but I intend moving them into a different class and calling it and its events from there.

Comment: Tou don't call them from a class but from an instance (object). To do so you need to hand a reference to the ControlHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Change your controls' visibility to public before you start accessing else create properties for getting and setting your controls to access it through form objects from any other class.

Comment: how about the events calling the events...thats where I actually need help

Comment: hmmm suppose button1_click is the event then you would be having a function like this:  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) .... so just change the visiblility to public for this function handling the event. :)

Comment: So in my form how do I call the control's events then. I'm doing something like this ControlHandler ch = new ControlHandler(), ch.CreateTextBox(some parameters). Now how do I assign this textbox to it's textbox_textchanged event in my ControlHandler class?

Comment: I am not getting that properly. What is the flow for this idea? Please explain your steps.

Comment: Ok I have a form and a class called ControlHandler. My class contains a return type function called CreateTextBox where I have created my dynamic textbox and attached it to an event called textbox_TextChanged using the code textbox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textbox_TextChanged). So I have an event like public void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) still in my class. So the question is how can I call that class from my form to display the textbox control and also attach it's event as well?